# Unable to remove empty git directory

Tags: 18.04, git, bug-reporting

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) on aarch64 and I'm unable to remove a Git directory in the `/tmp` directory. It says "`Directory not empty`" but, actually, it is. I have tried everything, but nothing works.

Here is what I see:

```
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/47': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/94': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/e6': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/65': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/8f': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/05': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/d9': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/1e': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/27': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/09': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/f5': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/f6': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/00': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/24': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/a2': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/30': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/b2': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/20': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/6e': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/e5': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/a9': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/81': Directory not empty
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/git/objects/be': Directory not empty
  File: /tmp/git/
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd01h/64769d    Inode: 549170      Links: 3
Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: ( 2000/cvar1984)   Gid: ( 9997/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2020-06-13 22:04:13.000000000 +0000
Modify: 2020-06-14 12:32:20.827870178 +0000
Change: 2020-06-14 12:52:23.357869719 +0000
 Birth: -
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/47
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/94
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/e6
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/65
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/8f
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/05
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/d9
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/1e
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/27
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/09
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/f5
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/f6
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/00
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/24
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/a2
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/30
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/b2
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/20
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/6e
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/e5
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/a9
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/81
4.0K    /tmp/git/objects/be
96K /tmp/git/objects
100K    /tmp/git/
100K    total
/tmp/git/
`-- objects
    |-- 00
    |-- 05
    |-- 09
    |-- 1e
    |-- 20
    |-- 24
    |-- 27
    |-- 30
    |-- 47
    |-- 65
    |-- 6e
    |-- 81
    |-- 8f
    |-- 94
    |-- a2
    |-- a9
    |-- b2
    |-- be
    |-- d9
    |-- e5
    |-- e6
    |-- f5
    `-- f6

24 directories, 0 files
```

How can I delete this directory?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: Should i paste it to pastebin or something?

Comment: You can paste text directly to your question. You can [edit] the question.

Comment: Why are you trying to delete files in /tmp? Just reboot and they should probably be gone.

Comment: I have try, but nothing works

Comment: @Cvar1984 I think you're not removing them recursively. Add -r to the rm command. I use rm -rf [name] when I delete directories. It says the directory is not empty, so there are probably some hidden files. Try ls -a to see them.

Comment: i have try remove it recursively using sudo rm -rf, rm -rf, i have change directory permission also, but it does't working